# Fallout shelter special training

Tags: fallout-shelter

I know that event responses are different, since characters go right back to their original assigned places.
What I'm wondering is if you have a character in a training room and swap them out (say, for a child that just turned into an adult), do you lose all training progress?

Comment: You mean if e.g. a single hour is left until point up and then take them out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, you do not lose progress by swapping Dwellers out of training. They go back at the same remaining-time as they had when they were removed from the room.

Comment: Can confirm that the game keeps track of dwellers' training progress. I'm _not_ certain if it does if a dweller goes exploring and returns, but I imagine it would.

Comment: @Samthere: Good point. I'll try and test it, shortly.

Comment: Wouldn't mind a source, but two testimonies make it seem pretty solid. Really good to know (I've been awkwardly waiting for the vault-mother to finish a training before making her pregnant again). I imagine this will be extremely useful later on, when everyone has high SPECIAL's.

Comment: I can probably attempt proof-via-screenshot, but there isn't a lot of official documentation for the game (that I've seen, or is publicly available).

Comment: Before I go to bed at night, I switch all of my trainees to train long train stats, and when I move them back in the morning they have not lost progress. If you've got a spare time to micromanage, it's definitely worth putting people in training rooms for their low stats and then switch them to longer sessions when you've got to be afk for a while.

Comment: I can confirm this too. I sent a female dweller to the barrack, then put her back to training after she got pregnant. She almost immediately got her SPECIAL increase. From a programmer's point of view, I believe it's likely the SPECIAL are floats (that is: they're not just 1 or 2, but can be 1.0003 for instance). If that's the case, they should keep their progress even if they're sent to the wastelands or die.